# in servlet Filter's method doFilter does not call

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

i have to create a program to login on facebook using example

http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/wiki/Examples

but when i run project then i get my doFilter method does not call after complete init method

Comment: Please give us the servlet and filter configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `init()` will be called on server's startup. The `doFilter()` will only be called when a HTTP request has been fired which matches the `url-pattern` of the Filter as definied in `web.xml`.

The easiest way to fire a HTTP request is using a webbrowser. For example [Firefox](http://getfirefox.com). Enter the desired URL matching the Filter's `url-pattern` in the address bar.